# How to add Html table dyanamically from C# code in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have to add the row in table by validating some condition in page load event of an `.aspx.cs` page.

Currently, I have this table in my `.aspx`:

```html
<table id="Bodyheight" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td class="leftNav">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td style="height: 2px;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="dis">
        <a id="DisclaimerManager" href="#" onfocus="blur()" onclick="iframeSrcChange('Home/Disclaimer.aspx')">
        Report Disclaimer</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="sub">
        <a id="SubmitionManager" href="#" onfocus="blur()" onclick="iframeSrcChange('Home/Submit.aspx')">
        Report Submitted</a>
    </td>
</tr>
.....
```

How can I do this from C#??

Comment: Do you want to add a row or a table ?

Comment: You can use a collection the you loop through.

Comment: i need to add the field like Report Disclaimer, Report Submitted,etc from c# and onclick i need to navigate to another page as above...

Comment: @KarlGjertsen can u please elaborate about Collection or suggest be some blogs about it

Answer (score 2):

Mark your Table element with `Runat="server"` and an `Id` value. Then you should be able to access this form element from your code behind and will be able to dynamically add Table rows and Cells as needed.

Quick example . This will add 10 rows to the table, each with once cell.

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    TableCell td = new TableCell();
    td.Text = "Value of " + i;

    tr.Cells.Add(td);

    myTable.Rows.Add(tr);

}
```

And your .aspx page should have this inside the form tag.

```
<asp:Table runat="server" id="myTable">
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do it that way!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public collection in your code behind page, you can access it from the HTML.

You can build the table in HTML and then add rows using a `foreach` block to enumerate the items.

Assuming you have a collection called `myPublicCollection`, with a single property called `Property1`, then you can do this:

```
<table>
    <% foreach(var item in myPublicCollection) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><% item.Property1 %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

The syntax might be a little out, as I've been working in MVC and my asp.net is a bit rusty!